# Why spring-data-jpa is not creating tables in MS SQL server?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I use in-memory(h2) database, spring-data-jpa is creating tables, but, when I change datasource to point to MS SQL (2017), I cannot see tables getting created.

Can anyone help me to solve this scenario?

Note: I'm using spring boot in my project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configured: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

It's hibernate how creates tables and not Spring Data JPA.